# Linkage Error on running sonar analysis from command line (maven project)

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, okhttp, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to run sonar analysis for my maven project using a remote sonar server. PFB the versions of sonar and the java that I tried using:

```
Maven Sonar Plugin : 3.5.0.1254
Java version : 1.7 and 1.8 (tried both)
SonarQube version: 8.3.0
```

This is the error I get. I tried updating version of java to 1.8, but I'm still facing an issue 
Error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar  on project <project_name>: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:so
nar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5.0.1254:sonar: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "okhttp3/EventListener$Factory.create(Lokhttp3/Call;)Lokhttp3/EventListener;" during creation of class "okhttp3/EventListener$$Lambda$123/000000000FBD1C60": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassL
oader@63d13f09" of class "okhttp3/EventListener$$Lambda$123/000000000FBD1C60" and loader "org/sonar/classloader/ClassRealm@eaecd3ff" of class "okhttp3/EventListener$Factory" have different types for the method signature
```

Couldn't get any valid references for this issue anywhere .Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Use a newer version of sonar-maven-plugin  https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.7.0.1746/maven-plugin

Comment: @khmarbaise  : I tried upgrading to 3.7.0.1746 and still facing the same.Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise : I am using Maven 3.3.9

Comment: I'm using gradle project and i'm also facing same error. SonarQube Version7.9.4. Gradle 4.10. Java 8

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I found that the issue was because of IBM jdk8 i was using. So I changed it openjdk8 in env variable JAVA_HOME as well. It works fine now.